# Hyperledger Fabric: Understanding Docker Containers

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

### Backgroud

I have been following the tutorial [Build Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html) with docker containers deployed on my localhost. However, I am uncertain some of the files inside the containers and I need clarification.

### Peer container

1. Inside the directory `/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes`, there is a file `mycc.1.0`, which is compiled I guess. Is it true that this chaincode is installed when running `peer chaincode install` in the cli container? And is `mycc.1.0` the system chaincodes?
2. Inside the directory `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData` , there are many other directories and files as shown below. I have a rough idea that it stores the world state and the blockchain. But what are the details in each directories?

   - `bookkeeper`
   - `chains`
   - `configHistory`
   - `historyLeveldb`
   - `ledgerProvider`
   - `pvtdataStore`
   - `stateLeveldb`
3. Inside the directory `/var/hyperledger/production/transientStore`, there are several files.

   - `000001.log`
   - `CURRENT`
   - `LOCK`
   - `LOG`
   - `MANIFEST-000000`

I also noticed that these files (with the same name but not sure if the context is the same or not) are found on those directories listed in point 2 above. So what is the difference or relation between `transientStore` and `ledgersData`?

### Orderer container

1. Inside the directory`/var/hyperledger/orderer`, there are `msp` and `tls` crypto-materials. But what is the purpose of `orderer.genesis.block`? Is it just used for bootstrap the blockchain network? After exploring this file, I found that it consists of certificates and ACL. Are these materials also used for monitoring the channel policy as well as verifying the transactions?
2. Inside the directory `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer`. There are two directories `chains` and `index`. They look very similar to the `chains` directory in peer container. But I still don't know what are these files.

The above containers have the name `peer#.org#.example.com` and `orderer.example.com`. But when I run `docker container ls`, I find that there are `dev-peer#.org#.example.com-mycc-1.0` docker containers. But I have no idea why they are here.

Thanks!

---

**Update**

1. Added point 3 concerning `transientStore` as shown in Peer container section (see above)
2. I noticed that in `base/docker-compose-base.yaml`, there is a volume mount like this `/var/run/:/host/var/run/`. Those files seem to be my local stuff and may not be related to hyperledger fabric. Why mount this volume?

Answer (score 3):

### Peer container

`/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes` - this is where installed chaincode packages are stored.

### Orderer container

`orderer.genesis.block` is the bootstrap block for the orderer ... it contains the basic orderer settings and the crypto material for the orderer organization.
The orderer organization has the ability to create consortiums and add members to them.  The consortium policies will then dictate who is able to create channels, etc.

`chains` - the raw ledger files for each channel

### dev-peer#.org#.example.com-mycc-1.0

These are the chaincode containers.  Fabric launches chaincode in Docker containers.

Comment: had to run ... will fill in more later .. but the other files for the peer pertain to the raw public and private ledger files, the raw public and private state storage files if you use leveldb, assorted ledger mgmt files

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I noticed that this link here, https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/history/historydb/historyleveldb, discusses `historyleveldb` but I still don't know exactly their purposes.